# What oauthScope should I use so that setDescription() does not trow "Action not allowed" exeption?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

My Google's birthday calendar does not show the contact's age.
So I rewrote&edited a code (google Apps Scripts) I found online that works with Calendar & Contacts apps which is supposed to overwrite calendar's event description into something like this "Arthur's - 19. birthday".
But I'm stuck with setDescription() method throwing "**Action not allowed**" exception.

The scopes in .json file is:

```
    {
      "oauthScopes" : [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
        "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds",
        "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds"
      ],
      "timeZone": "Europe/Belgrade",
      "dependencies": {
      },
      "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
      "runtimeVersion": "V8"
    }
```

The google-apps script is:

```
function calculateAge() {

  // Get all Contacts with birthdays set.
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var contactsWithBDays = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    var contact = contacts[i];
    var contactBDay = contact.getDates(ContactsApp.Field.BIRTHDAY);
    if ('undefined' !== typeof contactBDay && contactBDay.length) {
      contactsWithBDays.push({
        'fullName': contact.getFullName(),
        'birthdayDay': contactBDay[0].getDay(),
        'birthdayMonth': contactBDay[0].getMonth(),
        'birthdayYear': contactBDay[0].getYear(),
      })
    }
  }
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(contactsWithBDays));

  // Select date range of current year
  var currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();
  var start = new Date(currentYear + '-01-01');
  var end = new Date(currentYear + '-12-31');
  
  // Fetch events from Birthday Calendar
  var birthdayCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com");
  var bDayEvents = birthdayCal.getEvents(start, end);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < bDayEvents.length; i++) {
    var bDayEvent = bDayEvents[i];

    // Get Contact's display name
    var contactDisplayName = bDayEvent.getTitle().split(" - ")[1];
 
    for(var l = 0; l < contactsWithBDays.length; l++) {
      var contactWithBDay = contactsWithBDays[l];
      if (contactDisplayName === contactWithBDay.fullName) {
        var age = Math.round(currentYear - parseInt(contactWithBDay.birthdayYear));
        var newDescription = contactDisplayName + ' - ' + age + '. birthday!';
        Logger.log(newDescription);
        bDayEvent.setDescription("newDescription");
        contactsWithBDays.splice(l, 1);//I think this is the problem
        break;
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message you are receiving? Moreover, do you have access to this calendar?

Comment: There found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#setDescription(String)

Comment: I do have access to this calendar, it's default calendar of my birthday contacts. The error I receive is this: "Exception: Action not allowed".

Comment: @Cooper, as you can see from the .json file I attached - I already used those two scopes, that's what's bothers me.

Comment: Are you sure you want quotes here `bDayEvent.setDescription("newDescription");`

Comment: Why are you deleting items from the array that you are looping on? Your index is going get larger than the number that are left.  Quit doing that and you'll probably be okay.

Comment: `setDescription()` should receive and object, and you're passing a string. Remove the quotes so that `bDayEvent.setDescription("newDescription");` becomes `bDayEvent.setDescription(newDescription);`

Comment: Sorry, I left the quotes around the newDescription since I was debugging. Even without the quotes - it's throwing the same exception, and it expects me to pass the string https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#setDescription(String)

Answer (score 0):

#### It looks like what you are experiencing is in fact the expected behavior in this situation.

If you check the documentation regarding the **Birthdays** calendar [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084659#zippy=%2Cedit-or-remove-individual-birthdays):

> Birthdays come from details in your Google Contacts.

Therefore, any edits should be done in the Contacts side and not on the Calendar side. Moreover, if you check solely the **Birthdays** calendar, you can see that the events are not editable through the UI either.

*What you can do...*

Create a new calendar and add the birthdays there. In this way you will have more freedom when it comes to customizing the events to your needs.

#### Reference

- [Add or remove birthdays, holidays, and other calendars](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084659#zippy=%2Cedit-or-remove-individual-birthdays).